# Extract partial string from a pattern based on input

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

Example1

```
string: "999 someString"
pattern: "{id} {value}"
key: "id"
expected result: "999"
```

Example2

```
string: "D-12345 ABcdE"
pattern: "D-{id} {value}"
key: "value"
expected result: "ABcdE"
```

Example3

```
string: "abcde 000-strING"
pattern: "abcde {id}-{value}"
key: "value"
expected result: "strING"
```

Example4

```
string: "aaa-123-bbb"
pattern: "aaa-{id}-{value}"
key: "id"
expected result: "123"
```

I want to write a function that can receive string, pattern, and key and this function can return the expected result.
Something like

```
const stringExtractor = (string, pattern, key) => {
...
return result
}
```

I know this is something that might need to be done by Regex, but I have no idea how I can define the Regex.

Comment: I dont see consistency in pattern

Comment: Sadly you have to define a schema in your pattern

Comment: yes, string comes from the pattern, but the pattern is not always the same. Id and value might always appear in the pattern, but something may append to the pattern and make the pattern look different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `/([^}]*){([^}]+)}([^{]*)/` to get each *block* from the pattern. A block is the seperator before `{}`, the key inside `{}` and the seperator after `{}` and get each of those parts to separate matching groups. Use `exec` and loop through each block.

```js
function stringExtractor(string, pattern, key) {
  let block = /([^}]*){([^}]+)}([^{]*)/g,
      patternMatch;

  while (patternMatch = block.exec(pattern)) {
    const [, before, k, after] = patternMatch,
          partial = new RegExp(`${before}(.*?)${after || '$'}`);

    if (k === key)
      return string.match(partial)[1]
    else
      string = string.replace(new RegExp(partial), '')
  }
}

console.log(stringExtractor("999 someString", "{id} {value}", "value"))
console.log(stringExtractor("D-12345 ABcdE", "D-{id} {value}", "id"))
console.log(stringExtractor("aaa-123-bbb", "aaa-{id}-{value}", "id"))

console.log(stringExtractor("135236-374", "1{v1}2{v2}-{v3}4", "v2"))
console.log(stringExtractor("abc-234d-100efg", "ab{v1}d-10{v2}", "v2"))
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible if separators is also part of the value?
Like the example 
`
 // output should be 'some String'
stringExtractor("999 some String", "{id} {value}", "value")
`

Comment: @willie012328 I have updated for when the separator is inside an unrelated key

Answer (score 0):

Worst code with good result

**Warring:**  Code Fail if the pattern is like `{id}{value}`

Really want to see the good answer from other community members like using `Regex`

```js
let e1 = { string: "999 someString", pattern: "{id} {value}", key: "id" };
let e2 = { string: "D-12345 ABcdE", pattern: "D-{id} {value}", key: "value" };
let e3 = {
  string: "abcde 000-strING",
  pattern: "abcde {id}-{value}",
  key: "value",
};
let e4 = { string: "aaa-123-bbb", pattern: "aaa-{id}-{value}", key: "id" };

const stringExtractor = ({ string, pattern, key }) => {
  let tempKey = `{${key}}`;
  let tempString = string;

  let keyStartIndex = pattern.indexOf(tempKey);
  let keyLastIndex = keyStartIndex + tempKey.length;

  let before = pattern.substring(0, keyStartIndex);
  let after = pattern.substring(keyLastIndex);

  let isBeforeMatch = string.includes(before);
  let isAfterMatch = string.includes(after);

  tempString = tempString.replace(before, "");
  tempString = tempString.replace(after, "");

  if (isBeforeMatch) {
    tempString = tempString.split(after.substring(0, 1))[0];
  } else if (isAfterMatch) {
    let _l = before.length - 1;
    tempString = tempString.split(before.substring(_l))[1];
  }

  return tempString;
};
console.log("Example 1 => ", stringExtractor(e1));
console.log("Example 2 => ", stringExtractor(e2));
console.log("Example 3 => ", stringExtractor(e3));
console.log("Example 4 => ", stringExtractor(e4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic  commented in the code. Finding the separator between `{id}` and `{value}`. Then finding all the other elements from pattern and replacing the same in string. Then splitting the string with the separator and return based on the key.

```
const stringExtractor = (string, pattern, key) => {
  let seperator = pattern.substr(pattern.indexOf('{'), pattern.lastIndexOf('}')).replace(/{id}|{value}/g, ""); // finding the separator between {id} and {value}
  let otherElements = pattern.replace("{id}" + seperator + "{value}", ""); // finding other elements other than our {id} {value}
  if (!!otherElements) {
    string = string.replace(otherElements, ""); // removing other elements
  }
  let resultArray = string.split(seperator);
  return key == 'id' ? resultArray[0] : resultArray[1]; // this is hardcoded, can make dynamic
}
```